# Array not updating with values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I'm trying to run through a column of values, compare it to a supplied string, if it matches the string, add the value 4 columns over into an array, then sum the array at the end of the function.

The function exits out (not fails) at the ReDim Preserve line.

If I comment that out, it fails at the SumArray(Count) line.

What am I missing?

```
'Function used to SUM 
 Public Function TotalSum(prefix As String, rng As Range) As Integer
 Dim BookofDaveSum As Dictionary
 Set BookofDaveSum = New Dictionary
 Dim SumArray As Variant
 Dim Count As Long

 Dim cell As Range
 Dim i As Integer

Count = 0

 For Each cell In rng
    If Left(cell.Value, 7) = prefix Then
        If Not BookofDaveSum.Exists(cell.Value2) Then
            BookofDaveSum.Add cell.Value2, 0
            ReDim Preserve SumArray(0 To Count)
            SumArray(Count) = cell.Offset(0, 4)
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    End If
 Next cell

TotalSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumArray)

End Function
```

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you get an error message?  When the ReDim line exits out, where does it end up?

Comment: I'm using it as a function called from an Excel cell. =TotalSum(A1,A1:A2000) 
Stepping through the code, it just exists out of the vba steps and returns to the cell.

Comment: `Dim SumArray() As Variant` may help?  Is this not SUMIF(s)?  You are only handling one column `SumArray(Count) = cell.Offset(0, 4)` this way?

Comment: Why use the array at all?  You are not doing anything with it.  There is no output to the function.  Just remove the array and use `TotalSum = TotalSum + cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That did it!! What's so special about the ()? Mark your comment as the answer and I'll tick it. Thanks all.

Comment: You didn't include a reference to the function to set it equals to. Put TotalSum = something...

Comment: @ScottCraner I hadn't gotten to the output yet. It will return back as the function output as an Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumArray)

Comment: Why the extra steps?  That seem overly complicated.

Comment: Updated to show omitted last line.

Comment: @ScottCraner TotalSum = TotalSum + cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2 That seems cleaner however also jumps back to the Excel cell with no feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are iterating the range you are not gaining anything by using the array.  Simply keep a running total:

```
Public Function TotalSum(prefix As String, rng As Range) As Integer

Dim BookofDaveSum As Dictionary
Set BookofDaveSum = New Dictionary

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
   If Left(cell.Value, 7) = prefix Then
       If Not BookofDaveSum.Exists(cell.Value2) Then
           TotalSum = TotalSum + cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2
       End If
   End If
Next cell

End Function
```

---

If your concern is speed then convert both ranges to arrays and iterate the array:

```
Public Function TotalSum(prefix As String, rng As Range) As Long

Dim BookofDaveSum As Dictionary
Set BookofDaveSum = New Dictionary

Dim chRng As Variant
chRng = rng.Value2

Dim addRng As Variant
addRng = rng.Offset(, 4).Value2

Dim temp As Long
temp = 0

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(chRng, 1) To UBound(chRng, 1)
   If Left(chRng(i, 1), 7) = prefix Then
       If Not BookofDaveSum.Exists(chRng(i, 1)) Then
           temp = temp + addRng(i, 1)
       End If
   End If
Next cell

TotalSum = temp

End Function
```

---

Also this can be done with a formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((LEFT(A1:A10,7)="abcdefg")*(E1:E10))/(COUNTIFS(A1:A10,A1:A10,A1:A10,"abcdefg" &"*")+(LEFT(A1:A10,7)<>"abcdefg")))
```

Where `abcdefg` is your prefix, `A1:A10` is the string to test and `E1:E10` the values to add

Comment: This second option worked perfectly. I tried the Formula previously but didn't have much luck. Thank you for the detailed explanations and examples.

Comment: Not sure.  please ask a new question with the code you are trying.  But before you do, step through the code and find the line that it exits.  Then look at your data to ensure that it make sense.

Comment: @Scott_Craner I thought I had solved my own follow-up but not so. 
I've tried inverting it to sum when <> prefix (also tried If Not) both of these return a #Value. Is this something to do with how the array is set up?

Comment: See comment above.  It could be many things.  You will need to step through the code and see if the data is the issue.  remember that you are trying to add everything in the offset range that does not equal which may include cells with text.  It is most likely the data being added that is causing the issue.

Comment: "which may include cells with text." Just so nonchalantly fixed my problem. The range now included the header which it didn't like. If I could mark this comment as solved, I would! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Dim SumArray() As Variant` you are trying to redim a variable not an array. `()` indicates you want an array of variants.